# Why does MVC4 validate js auto adds number validation to datetime?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I've recently upgraded to MVC 4 and use validate.js and validate.unobtrosive.js for client side validation. Since MVC 4 I notice the html ouput has changed.

MVC3:

```
<input class="dutchDate date_datepicker hasDatepicker" id="FirstDate" name="FirstDate" type="text" value="18-02-2015">
```

MVC4:

```
<input class="dutchDate date_datepicker hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-number="Waarde moet numeriek zijn" id="FirstDate" name="FirstDate" type="text" value="18-02-2015">
```

So now the datetime field gets validated by my custom validation AND by the number validation. I don't understand why the number validation is being added to the input tag. Has some experienced the same? I don't want number validation on my date input.

Model:

```
public class TripFilter : IResultFilter
{
    ...
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? FirstDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? UntilDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Renderering:

```
@Html.TextBox("", dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), new { @class = ViewData["class"] + " dutchDate date_datepicker", @type = "text" }
```

### Edit

After some checking in the Global asax I've noticed the following line:

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new ClientNumberValidatorProvider());
```

Which does the following:

```
public class ClientNumberValidatorProvider : ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider
{
    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        bool isNumericField = base.GetValidators(metadata, context).Any();
        if (isNumericField)
            yield return new ClientSideNumberValidator(metadata, context);
    }
}

public class ClientSideNumberValidator : ModelValidator
{
    public ClientSideNumberValidator(ModelMetadata metadata,
        ControllerContext controllerContext)
        : base(metadata, controllerContext) { }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
    {
        yield break; // Do nothing for server-side validation
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "number",
            ErrorMessage = Resources.Global.InvalidField
        };
    }
}
```

It seems this is the cause of adding the number validation. What confuses me now is that why does this only happen to DateTime fields and not String fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by adjusting the ClientNumberValidatorProvider. It now looks like this:

```
public class ClientNumberValidatorProvider : ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider
{
    private static readonly HashSet<Type> numericTypes = new HashSet<Type>(new Type[]
    {
        typeof(byte), typeof(sbyte),
        typeof(short), typeof(ushort),
        typeof(int), typeof(uint),
        typeof(long), typeof(ulong),
        typeof(float), typeof(double), typeof(decimal)
    });

    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (numericTypes.Contains(metadata.ModelType))
            yield return new ClientSideNumberValidator(metadata, context);
    }
}
```

It will only return the ClientSideNumberValidator if the property of the model is one of the types in the HashSet. Thanks Peter Smith to pointing me out to the wright direction. The HashSet is used by MicroSoft too: [ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.cs](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.cs)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it by adding

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

to `Application_Start` in `Global.asax.cs`

This works with all value types - `string` is not a value type, `DateTime`is. You should not need to change the `ClientNumberValidatorProvider`

Comment: Thank you for pointing me out to Global asax. I've discovered that the ClientNumberValidatorProvider is the cause of this problem. See the Edit part of my question.

Comment: See the additions in my answer above

Answer (score 0):

MVC 4 is generating those attriutes because you are using unobtrusivevalidation as setted in you web.config:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

you can set those properties to false in your web.config :

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />
```

But i suppose you really want to validate your date on client side so you have to use `@Html.TextBoxFor` instead of `@Html.TextBox`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FirstDate)
```

Or even better create a template called `DateTime.cshtml` under `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` and then use `@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.FirstDate)`
the template could be something like this (with your proper markup and attributes):

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    var value = "";
    const string format = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}";
    if (Model.HasValue) {
        value = string.Format(format, Model.Value);
    }
}

<label class="form-group">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    @Html.TextBox("", null,
        new
        {
            @class = "form-control date", placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName ?? ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName,
            data_format = "dd/mm/yy HH:ii P",
            data_initial_value = value
        })
</label>
```

The `EditFor`helper will infer automatically the type of the property your are passing over and use the template called as the type in this case `DateTime`.
Note that the template is also typed with `@model DateTime?` that allow to handle null dates also.